Why are the Watson Crick base pairs normally found in RNA helices cis with respect to the glycosidic bonds?
I know that Watson Crick base pairs found in RNA helices are cis with respect to their glycosidic bonds, but I am having great difficulty seeing why this is true. Since RNA secondary structure is defined by a single RNA strand that loops back on itself forming helices, it seems to me that nucleotides in an RNA helix should have their 5' phosphate groups oriented in opposite directions, which should make their glycosidic bonds trans. Is there no relationship between the direction of the glycosidic bond and the orientation of the phosphate group? What am I missing here?

I am afraid that without a diagram to illustrate what “you know” very few members of this list will be able to follow it, never mind answer it. Certainly I can’t. Only real specialists can talk about structure envisaging it intheir mind. At the very least reference a paper or web page illustrating your point.

@David Page 501 of this paper provides a useful illustration, and I think enough information to answer the question.  We see the antiparallel helices both interacting at W-C surfaces will be cis when antiparallel.  Cis is defined as both sugar backbones on the same side in the plane of the bases (creating a minor groove), NOT phosphates both on the same side in the plane of the backbones.  I'll leave this as a comment because (a) I could be wrong and (b) it's a hard one to talk about in a way that makes sense.
